# Angular dynamic form group inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

So I have a form that has some basic family information.  Then I want to have part of the form to add in children of the family.  I'm using reactive forms, that looks something like this:

```
    this.details = fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      phone: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

Now, at some point in the UI, there will be inputs for children names, with the option to add more.  Can I programatically add more input fields to the `this.details` group?

**Update**

@incognito's answer is perfect for the original question I asked.  It shall remain the selected answer.  While doing some digging on his answer I also found FormArray, which is the direction I ended up going, so I wanted to add that here.  It looks like:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  ...
  children: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      age: ['', Validators.required],
      gender: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  ])
});
```

Then, the view looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let child of form.controls.children.controls; let i = index;"
         formArrayName="children"
         class="childForm">
        <div [formGroupName]="i"
             class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       formControlName="name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number"
                       class="form-control"
                       formControlName="age">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control"
                        formControlName="gender">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addChild()"
            class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Another Child
    </button>
</form>
```

And the `addChild` function referenced in the button at the bottom of the form looks like:

```
addChild() {
  const children = <FormArray>this.form.get('children');
  children.push(this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    age: [''],
    gender: ['']
  }));
}
```

So, again, this is a different way of going about it, and I only discovered it after digging in on @incognito's answer.  Thanks @incognito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Implementation might be better, but something like this:

```
<button (click)="addKid()"> Add kid </button

numberOfKids: number = 0;

addKid() {
 this.numberOfKids++;
 let input = this.renderer.createElement('input');
 this.renderer.appendChild(form, input);
 this.renderer.setProperty(input, 'formControlName', this.numberOfKids); 

 this.details.addControl(this.numberOfKids, new FormControl(''));
}
```

So every formControl for every kid will be named as a number.

This implementation is based on Renderer2 (recommended way to "directly" manipulate DOM elements)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you @incognito!

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer let me to discover FormArray as well, which allows for a repeating section based on the controls of the parent formGroup.  Then the rendering of fields dynamically isn't required.  This answer certainly satisfies my original question, but wanted to mention FormArray as another way to go about solutioning this.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Greg! I will check it. I guess FormArray would be more efficient.